# flutter pub run build_runner build failed

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

flutter version:

```
flutter_macos_v1.9.1+hotfix.2-stable
```

create new project in terminal:

```
flutter create myapp
```

open vscode, edit `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  json_annotation: ^3.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.7.0
  json_serializable: ^3.2.2
```

get packages in terminal:

```
flutter pub get
```

new `/lib/user.dart` and filling below:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'user.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class User extends Object {
  @JsonKey(name: 'seed')
  String seed;

  @JsonKey(name: 'results')
  int results;

  @JsonKey(name: 'page')
  int page;

  @JsonKey(name: 'version')
  String version;

  User(
    this.seed,
    this.results,
    this.page,
    this.version,
  );

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> srcJson) =>
      _$UserFromJson(srcJson);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserToJson(this);
}
```

run `flutter pub run build_runner build` in terminal:

```
[INFO] Generating build script...
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 321ms

[INFO] Creating build script snapshot......
[INFO] Creating build script snapshot... completed, took 10.4s

[INFO] Initializing inputs
[INFO] Building new asset graph...
[INFO] Building new asset graph completed, took 698ms

[INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs....
[INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs. completed, took 2ms

[INFO] Running build...
[SEVERE] json_serializable:json_serializable on lib/user.dart:

Invalid argument(s): Path must be absolute : dart:core
[SEVERE] json_serializable:json_serializable on lib/main.dart:

Invalid argument(s): Path must be absolute : dart:core
[SEVERE] json_serializable:json_serializable on test/widget_test.dart:

Invalid argument(s): Path must be absolute : dart:core
[INFO] Running build completed, took 1.5s

[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph...
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 36ms

[SEVERE] Failed after 1.6s
```

why never succeeded?!

Comment: Describe what you try to achieve instead of only posting the code, that would help others understand the question. Do not try to bypass stackoverflow restrictions

Comment: Dart 2.0 has some sort of bug with that same error message. https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33551

Comment: He's trying to automage Json serialization, as i am, and running into the same kind of error. Doesn't make any sense. This is what we're following: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-using-code-generation-libraries

HELP

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have the same issue. I cannot figure it out.

Comment: @bradbury9 automated json serialization/deserialization, check my other comment

Comment: I'm having the same issue using Moor. :\

Comment: make sure the class name is same with the generated file name. For ex:
part 'User.g.dart';
class User {
}

Answer (score 107):

Try this.

```
flutter pub get && flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Comment: For web version, just append web... `flutter pub get && flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs web`

Comment: For some reason, I am forced to run flutter pub get every time even though there isn't anything to get. But it's just a minor inconvenience...

Answer (score 44):

add dependency in pubsec.yaml, analyzer: '0.39.14'

```
flutter clean
flutter pub cache repair
flutter pub run build_runner clean
```

Then run,

```
flutter pub run build_runner build
```

Comment: add `flutter pub get` after `flutter pub run build_runner clean` and it worked for me!

Comment: worked for me with ```flutter pub run build_runner clean```

Comment: Finally! This worked for me, when everything else failed.

Answer (score 29):

I tried with many solutions, But error not gone. `flutter packages pub run build_runner watch` command ran with endless log.

I deleted **pubspec.lock** and ran `flutter pub get` and installed dependency again and ran above command. After this error gone.

Comment: This really helped to solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: this should be accepted answer!

Comment: you solved my hours! thank you!

Comment: This one solved issue for ../pub_semver-2.1.1/lib/src/version_constraint.dart:96:13: Error: Method not found: 'FallThroughError'. for me.

Comment: Deleting the `pubspec.lock` file, followed by reinstalling the dependencies, solved the issue for me. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, so I just saved the changes first in the class (in your case `User` class).
And then I just retried using:

```
flutter pub run build_runner build
```

Comment: This answer worked for me. I was stuck trying to get `graphql_codegen` building and the docs say `dart run build_runner build`, but even swapping out _dart_ with _flutter_ wouldn't work. The trick was adding _pub_ just like you have it here: `flutter pub run build_runner build`

Comment: I maybe too late but this worked for me too, you need to save the changes first then run flutter pub run build_runner build

Answer (score 8):

Please create default empty constructor for models class before `flutter packages pub run build_runner build` command

Answer (score 3):

It might not be the case in this situation, but I had a similar problem caused by my auto formatter removing this line:

```
part 'my_class.g.dart';
```

Once I added that line and ran the command again it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

I got this to work with the latest build_runner and json_serializable versions after a long process of trying all of the above suggestions:
build_runner: ^1.10.2
json_serializable: ^3.4.0
Not sure what ultimately worked, but looks like one of the issues in my case was a slightly outdated dart SDK, so that's one more thing to keep an eye on

Comment: Thanks for this answer! build_runner: ^1.10.2 requires Dart version 2.-10.0+, therefore, I changed the version to 1.10.1, and luckily it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

### Successfully generating all *.g.dart files with:

build_runner 0.9.2

json_serializable 0.5.8+1

json_annotation 0.2.9+1

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Analyzer is breaking it, downgrading to `analyzer: 0.38.2` solved it for me.

Source: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/38499#issuecomment-533812652

Comment: Had the issue using Moor and this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. I simply installed the build runner package
in pubspec.yaml file like -

dev_dependencies:

build_runner: ^1.3.1

mobx_codegen: ^0.3.9

Answer (score 1):

you may need hive_generator in your dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Update 2020/8/24:
seems to break build_runner or json_serializable in version:

```
Analyzer: 0.39.16
```

Going back to dart analyzer version:

```
Analyzer: 0.39.14
```

fixed it for me.
So, something is broken in 0.39.16.

Comment: i had an analyzer issue as well, however i wasn't as far as i was aware using it. Neither had i specified a versino to use. So i assumed that this was a cache issue and ran flutter clean and flutter pub get to hopefully reset the cache. I also found out that intellij had automatically commited my .g.dart files, which breaks the runner. So could be erroneous reporting. Who knows.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the class name is same with the generated file name. For ex:

> part '**User**.g.dart';
>
> class **User** {
>
> }

Comment: That's actually wrong, the class name part should be always lower case: `part 'user.g.dart'`

Comment: Actually it's correct, the 'part' should be the same as the file name, even if it starts with uppercase

Answer (score 0):

My class name was:

```
class Game
```

but my filename was `game_model.dart`
So you'll need to use:

```
part 'game_model.g.dart';
```

You may also need to add `hive_generator` dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `flutter clean` is resolving the issue. Try running it before i.e. openApi Generator.

Answer (score 0):

**This is working you should definitely try it**

I was getting the message "Success after 1.0 seconds with 0 output (0 actions)" when I used it with dart frog. He needed to create a "bin" file and put the factories in it so he could see it. This worked for me!

[image: Image of Code]

Comment: Please copy and paste the precise code or file tree here directly. Images are hard to read, have bad accessibility and deliver a lot of unnecessary information.

Answer (score 0):

In my side I edited the **build_runner_core-version** package source code outside my flutter project with adding a method to the class **BuildForInputLogger** in the following code below:

```
Stream<Level?> get onLevelChanged {
```

return Stream.empty();
}

And yeah it's worked to me

Answer (score 0):

First make sure to maintain small letter and underscore style here:

```
part 'course_box.g.dart';
```

Then, run this:

```
dart pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while running `flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs` but it was showing this error

```
Failed to build build_runner:build_runner:
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/watcher-1.0.2/lib/src/constructable_file_system_event.dart:7:57: Error: The class 'FileSystemEvent' can't be extended, implemented, or mixed in outside of its library because it's a sealed class.
```

After trying everything here without success, I simply did a `flutter pub get` and everything works well after when I did `flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`

Answer (score 0):

```
add hive_generator
flutter pub get 
flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

dependencies:

retrofit: '>=4.0.0 <5.0.0'

logger: any  #for logging purpose

json_annotation: ^4.8.1

dev_dependencies:

retrofit_generator: '>=7.0.0 <8.0.0'      // required dart >=2.19

build_runner: '>=2.3.0 <4.0.0'

json_serializable: ^6.6.2

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).